# Upload Validation for photos

Tags: javascript, validation, error-handling, file-upload

I got a javascript code like this to validate the file extension for my users when they upload pics on my server.It should allow both .jpg and .jpeg photos however only .jpg files are accepted and it invalidates if the photo ends with .jpeg.Here's the code:

```
function validate(x) {
    var extensions = new Array("jpg", "jpeg");
    var pos = x.lastIndexOf('.') + 1;
    var ext = x.substring(pos, x.length);
    var final_ext = ext.toLowerCase();
```

```
for (i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
    if (extensions[i] != final_ext) {

        return 0;
        break;
    }
    return 1;

}
```

}

what do you think is the problem?

Comment: As soon as you compare the final_ext to an extensions[] where they don't match it returns 0.  So as long as the first extension final_ext tests against is valid it would work.  Otherwise, if final_ext does not match the first extension you test against it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a regular expression instead

```
function validate(x) {
    return /.(jpg|jpeg)$/ig.test(x);
}
```

Comment: I was going to say to use the split method, but in this case a regular expression does indeed make more sense :)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys but matt's code work on my situation

Answer (score 6):

Should be

```
for (i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
    if (extensions[i] == final_ext) {
        return 1;
    }
}
return 0;
```

Note also that `return` immediately ends the current function, so putting a `break` after `return` is pointless.

Finally, if this Javascript is running on the client-side (i.e. in a web browser) keep in mind that the user may circumvent this (e.g. by using Firebug). You may wish to do checking at the server side too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it is going to compare the file extension against the first item in the list (.jpeg != .jpg) and return 0.  This means it won't get a chance to try the second extension in the list.

Probably best to set a flag in the comparison and not return until all items in the extension list have been compared against the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong. This is what the loop should look like:

```
for (i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
    if (extensions[i] == final_ext) {
        return 1;
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Lol. You added the return 0 statement at the end, too. Voted yours up ;)

Comment: @tvanover: Took the words out of my mouth.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
VALID_EXT = 'jpeg jpg';
function validate(x) {
  return +(VALID_EXT.split(/\s+/).indexOf(x.replace(/^.*\./,'').toLowerCase()) >= 0)
}
validate('file.jpeg');     // 1
validate('file.jpg');      // 1
validate('file.pic.jpg');  // 1
validate('file.gif');      // 0
```